# How do I make asksaveasfilename save files as images only and accessible in file directory?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently trying to work on a software solution in python that has a function that takes a screenshot of the screen and then save it.

So far I'm able to make the `asksaveasfilename` dialog appear, name it something like `test.png` and successfully save it, but when I open the file directory to open the file itself, Windows doesn't recognize it and says that the file has "moved or been removed".

The question is, how do I make it so that it can only save the file as a `.png` or `.jpg` and then save it properly so its accessible as a file in the file directory?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
import pyautogui as pyg
table = tk.Tk()
def screenshot():
    x = table.winfo_rootx()
    y = table.winfo_rooty()
    w = table.winfo_width()
    h = table.winfo_height()
    data = [("All Files", "*.*")]
    tablescreenshot = pyg.screenshot(region=(x,y,w,h))
    tablescreenshot = asksaveasfilename(filetypes = data, defaultextension=data)
for i in range(0,3):
   for j in range(0,3):
      cell = tk.Entry(table,width=10,font=('Verdana',10))
      cell.grid(row=i,column=j)

snap = tk.Button(table,text="Screenshot",command=screenshot)
snap.grid(row=i+1,column=j)

table.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code has never saved the screen shot to the file returned by `asksaveasfilename()`.  Also you used same variable for the image and the filename, so the image will be lost after executing `asksaveasfilename()`.

Comment: Can you clarify then what changes I need to make so that the code actually saves the screenshot to file then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues in your code:

- use same variable for screen shot image and output filename, so the image will be lost
- never call any function to save the screen shot image to the output filename

Below is modified code to fix the above issues:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
import pyautogui as pyg

table = tk.Tk()

def screenshot():
    x = table.winfo_rootx()
    y = table.winfo_rooty()
    w = table.winfo_width()
    h = table.winfo_height()
    data = [("Image Files", "*.png *.jpg")] # look up only PNG and JPG files
    tablescreenshot = pyg.screenshot(region=(x,y,w,h))
    # use another name for the output filename
    filename = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=data, defaultextension=data)
    if filename:
        # save the image to the output filename
        tablescreenshot.save(filename)

for i in range(0,3):
   for j in range(0,3):
      cell = tk.Entry(table, width=10, font=('Verdana',10))
      cell.grid(row=i, column=j)

snap = tk.Button(table, text="Screenshot", command=screenshot)
snap.grid(row=i+1, column=j)

table.mainloop()
```